# Open Generic Constraint

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following interface:

```
public interface IQuerySpec<M> { }
```

I would love to make an extension method like this:

```
public static OrderedSortation<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(
    this T query, 
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sort) 
where T : IQuerySpec<?> {
    //business as usual
}
```

I simply want to be sure that type `T` is some variation of `IQuerySpec<M>`.  I could then call the extension method as follows:

```
public class Foo : IQuerySpec<int> {
   public int SizeOfSailBoat {get; set;}
}

IQuerySpec<Foo> foo = new Foo {SizeOfSailBoat = 10}.
var result = foo.OrderBy(f => f.SizeOfSailBoat);
```

The UDT `Foo` was designated in the above example, but I don't care what generic type parameter is used.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried the following:

```
public static OrderedSortation<T> OrderBy<T, M, TKey>(
    this T query, 
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sort) 
where T : IQuerySpec<M> {
    //business as usual
}
```

The above works, but requires that the generic parameters are stated explicitly in order to invoke "OrderBy".  I don't want to be required to explicitly state the generic parameters.

I also tried this:

```
public interface IQuerySpec {}
public interface IQuerySpec<M> : IQuerySpec {}
```

With these interfaces I can then do this:

```
public static OrderedSortation<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(
    this T query, 
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sort) 
where T : IQuerySpec {
    //business as usual
}
```

This is almost good enough, except that I want to hide the non-generic IQuerySpec so that it is not visible outside my class library.  I would love if I could have scoped the non-generic interface this way:

```
internal interface IQuerySpec {}
```

Unfortunately the compiler will not let me do that.

I'm guessing what I want isn't possible, but asking just in case.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like the syntax of the usage to look like?

Comment: @Mike: I've added an invocation example.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the compiler cannot infer the type of M from T or T from M implicitly.

so you need to fix one them , here I fixed T to `IQuerySpec<M>`

and the signature of the extension method becomes

```
    public static OrderedSortation<IQuerySpec<M>> OrderBy<M, TKey>(
     this IQuerySpec<M> query,
     Expression<Func<IQuerySpec<M>, TKey>> sort)

    {
        //business as usual
    }
```

as An Example

```
    class IntQSpec : IQuerySpec<int>
    {
        //your implementation
    }
```

and here is the invocation example

```
var iQS = new IntQSpec();
//do whatever you want with iQS
var ord = iQS.OrderBy(ii=>ii.ToString());
//here I called OrderBy without the need to explicitly specifying the Generic Arguments
```

here is the test of your code on visual studio 2013-2015 , no error where highlighted
note that I accessed the Z field of concrete type `IntQSpec`
[image]

I hope it will help.

Comment: I've modified my question to clarify that the expression tree must be able to access members of the concrete IQuerySpec<M>.  In my example, I access "SizeOfSailBoat", which is available on the concrete `Foo` class, but not available on the IQuerySpec<M> interface.  So the example you have here won't work.

Comment: ok, If you use visual studio 2010 and earlier then the compiler fails to do what you want implicitly, but on visual studio 2013-2015 work without specifying the generic arguments

Comment: I'm using VS 2015.  In the example you've provided, you are passing `M` into the expression tree.  The expression tree must have access to `T` instead of `M`.

Comment: Yes, your newest example does work - I also used that same example in my question.  In my question I stated that a solution that uses a non-generic `IQuerySpec` is "almost good enough."   The problem is that if I must use a non-generic `IQuerySpec` interface, then I would like a way to hide it as `internal` - but that does not appear to be possible.

Comment: if you provide an example of what you really want, we may find a workaround the problem that you are facing

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `IQuerySpec<M>` is either not needed at all and should just be `IQuerySpec` or `TKey`should always be `M` based on what I'm seeing here.  I suspect that **replacing** and thereby eliminating `IQuerySpec<M>` with `IQuerySpec` is what you really want based on your desire that `M` be *open*.  Here is a proof.  Please see if it fits what you are trying to accomplish or if one of the steps on the way to the final solution is closer:

Assuming that `IQuerySpec<M>` is in fact needed and `M` should always equal `TKey`, the following compiles and would likely work with your implementation:

**Assuming `TKey` is `M`:**

```
public interface IQuerySpec<M> { }
public class OrderedSortation<T> {}
public static class IQuerySpecExtensions
{
    public static OrderedSortation<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(this T query, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sort) where T : IQuerySpec<TKey>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // business as usual
    }
}
public class Foo : IQuerySpec<int> { public int SizeOfSailBoat {get; set;} }
```

Usage:

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo {SizeOfSailBoat = 10};
        var result = foo.OrderBy(f => f.SizeOfSailBoat);
    }
}
```

**Assuming the need for multiple `TKey` options:**

If you need to support other properties of other types (*opening* the class for more querying possibilities), then your class might look like this for example:

```
public interface IQuerySpec<M> { }
public class OrderedSortation<T> {}
public static class IQuerySpecExtensions
{
    public static OrderedSortation<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(this T query, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sort) where T : IQuerySpec<TKey>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // business as usual
    }
}
public class Foo : IQuerySpec<int>, IQuerySpec<string>
{
    public int SizeOfSailBoat {get; set;}
    public string NameOfSailBoat {get; set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo {SizeOfSailBoat = 10};
        var result = foo.OrderBy(f => f.SizeOfSailBoat);
        result  = foo.OrderBy(f => f.NameOfSailBoat);
    }
}
```

**Reduce `IQuerySpec<M>` to `IQuerySpec`:**

In which case you could just simplify to only having `IQuerySpec` like this:

```
public interface IQuerySpec { }
public class OrderedSortation<T> {}
public static class IQuerySpecExtensions
{
    public static OrderedSortation<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(this T query, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sort) where T : IQuerySpec
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // business as usual
    }
}
public class Foo : IQuerySpec
{
    public int SizeOfSailBoat {get; set;}
    public string NameOfSailBoat {get; set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo {SizeOfSailBoat = 10};
        var result = foo.OrderBy(f => f.SizeOfSailBoat);
        result  = foo.OrderBy(f => f.NameOfSailBoat);
    }
}
```

All of the above works barring that there are no actual method or property signatures defined on IQuerySpec that refer to `M`.